# Is it possible to disable the cache in Firefox on a per-domain basis?

Tags: firefox, domain, browser-cache

I'm finding that when deploying changes to a web server running on my local machine, even Ctrl+F5 doesn't always get an un-cached copy of the page. I'd really like to be able to turn off caching for that particular domain (essentially my local host), but can't find an option to do that.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried Shift-F5?

Comment: Ah...Shift-F5 does nothing.

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd> will refresh the page, overwriting the cache.

If this isn't helping you (as you said) I would recommend trying out the [johnnycache](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/johnnycache/) add-on. I've never used this add-on but it seems to be what you're looking for.